# Centre Aligning Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I'm building an online CV and can't seem to get my navigation bar to centre align and have it horizontal going across the page. Currently vertical sitting to the left of the page.
Secondly, how would I be able to apply a flexbox or grid layout to my navigation bar?

```css
#toolbar h3 {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Baskerville;
    border: black;
    border-bottom-width: 100px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.nav{
    border:5px solid black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
   display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: black;
}


.nav li{
   display:flex;
    color: black;
    float: left;
}

.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}

#toolbar{
    background-color: silver;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#toolbar a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;

}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar">
    <p>
    <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#startAbout"><h3> About Me</h3></a></li>
    <li><a href="#startAcademic"><h3> Academic Profile</h3></a></li>
    <li><a href="#startExperience"><h3> Past Experience</h3></a></li>
</ul>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: display: flex and float: left to the same elements ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that your navigation bar is text-based and not image based. I personally dealt with this on my current project's webpage. What I would recommend is:

1. Instead of using unordered lists, group all the elements into a single H3. This will allow us to properly align your text.
2. Give this h3 either a class or ID. (If you plan to use this nav bar somewhere else, maybe on another page, use class.) It can be whatever you want. For this example, I will use navText.
3. Next, add the following code snippet to your CSS profile:

   .navText {
   text-align: center;
   }

This should solve the problem! If it does not, try using the `align` CSS element and setting it to center.

Have a great day!

Comment: Still to no avail I'm unable to get the navigation bar to the centre.

Comment: Can you please share the entirety of the code so I can get a grasp of how things are laid out and try to replicate it?

Comment: It wont let me post the entire code, keeps giving me the error "It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details". Any possible way to contact you?

Comment: Yes, there is! My email is daddyandwilliam@gmail.com and my Discord is ProgrammerPlays#8264.

Answer (score 0):

**RESULT**

[image]

---

You need to remove all float values and just add display: flex, see the live demo link below.

**CSS**

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

https://codepen.io/wilsonbalderrama/pen/MWYpBmw